# jQuery - trigger event when cookie contents change

Tags: jquery, events, cookies, bind

Let's say the cookie is called "CountDracula" and contains "1,2,3,4"

Then I use some Javascript function (which hasn't been written yet) to change the cookie to "2,3,4" or "1,2,3,4,99" (add or subtract a digit)

Can you trigger an event that the cookie updated (without reloading the page) to see the new contents of the cookie, even if it's just sending the updated contents to the console?  Essentially listen for cookie changes.

I just want to know if it's possible to make an event that detects the cookie has changed.

Update: Since I need a function to update the cookie anyway, updateCookie(), I can call my "cookieUpdated" code from there.  But I was hoping such an event would help me debug the updateCookie() function as I worked on it today, it would be cool to see the values change, verifying my code is working.  Maybe Firebug has the cookie value?  Now I'm thinking just make an alert in my updateCookie() function to show the contents of the cookie :-/

Comment: *"Or is that frowned upon?"* - In my opinion, yes. You shouldn't ask a question if you know that you could add more to it to make it easier to answer. Regarding your question, there's no events triggered when a cookie is changed/updated, but you could trigger custom events in your JavaScript method.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall that's the answer I was looking for.  Though I find it hard to believe.  Is the event hidden for security reasons?  Since I need a function to update the cookie anyway, updateCookie(), I can call my "cookieUpdated" code from there.  But I was hoping such an event would help me debug the updateCookie() function as I worked on it today.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom event:

```
$(document).on('cookieUpdate', function(){
    //update menu, whatever 
});
```

and trigger it once you changed your cookie:

```
$(document).trigger('cookieUpdate');
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as calling a function called cookieUpdate() is there any advantage?

Comment: It depends. If you want to do all the staff in one place e.g. update menu, save to DB then you can just encapsulate everything in into one function and call it on cookies update. With the event you can have as many different subscribers to that event as you want. They can work independently.